# Example on how to use IContextFunction in Eclipse 4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I read about `org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IContextFunction` but could not find online an actual example.
My understanding is that a component implements an `IContextFunction` and on calling `compute` another object is lazily created.
But how/when the `compute` method is called it is not clear to me.
For example with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0"   
  name="com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.translate">  

<implementation class="com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.Test"/>  

 <service>  
   <provide interface="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IContextFunction"/>  
 </service>  

 <property name="service.context.key" type="String"   
   value="com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.test"/>  

</scr:component>
```

someone must call for the `com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.test` for `compute` to be called but it is unclear to me how this is used.
Does anyone have an example reference?

Answer (score 5):

It is what gets injected into your pojos.
E.g.

```
public class YourPojo {
   @Inject
   @Named("com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.test")
   private Object yourObject;
}
```

OR

```
public class YourPojo {
   @Inject
   public void test(IEclipseContext ctx) {
        Object yourObject = ctx.get("com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.test");
   }
}
```

OR

```
public class YourPojo {
   @Inject
   public void test(@Named("com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.test") Object yourObject) {
      // consume yourObject
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes I found the second example you post after googling a lot.But could not find anything about the first example.When will the `Inject` of the `Named` variable happen for your first example?

Comment: It happens whenever your pojo is instantiated and under the DI engine's control. Though, if you know how the second example is meant to be used, the first is almost the same. The difference is that you just can do a lot more in the test() method than just setting/injecting the @Named field. You can consume your "com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.test" object in a command handler, for instance...

Comment: When you say `POJO` are you referring to `yourObject` **or** the class that has `yourObject` as a member? Because if I do `ctx.get("com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.test");` the member `yourObject` will not be automatically injected, right?That is why you are explicitly populating in the second example. Is the first example meant to work in a case where the object having `yourObject` as member is instantiated **after** the `ctx.get("com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contextservice.test");` is called somewhere in the code? Still not clear on the first example.

Comment: POJO = the class that needs yourObject. You may want to have a look at this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection (see "Injection Order" at the bottom). The field injection will happen before the method injection. I.e. if you debug and add a breakpoint to test(), the field should have already been injected.

Comment: So you are saying that calling `ctx.get` is mandatory for case 1 to work, right?

Comment: No, no. The two cases are just alternatives and independent of each other. You may either use the first or the second or even mix both at the same time.

Comment: If they are independent, when does case 1 occur?I managed to use case 2, but case 1 with the injection of `yourObject` is *never* set.Would it be possible to provide a small working example for case 1?